Logging in WebForms
I am working in a webforms in VB.Net. I was asked to integrate webforms with datadog for logging. So I have create a singleton class for logging as below

public class DatadogLogger
{
    private static DatadogLogger _instance;
    private static readonly RestClient _restClient = new RestClient();

    private DatadogLogger()
    {
    }

    public static DatadogLogger Log
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                _instance = new DatadogLogger();
            }

            return _instance;
        }
    }

        public void Error(string infoMessage, string actionName, string requestPath, string sourceContext, Exception exceptionDetail, string hostName, string userId)
        {
            DatadogCore(infoMessage, "Error", actionName, requestPath, sourceContext, exceptionDetail, hostName, userId);
        }

        public void Information(string infoMessage, string actionName, string requestPath, string sourceContext, string hostName, string userId = null)
        {
            DatadogCore(infoMessage, "Information", actionName, requestPath, sourceContext, null, hostName, userId);
        }

private void DatadogCore(string infoMessage, string levelInfo, string actionName, string requestPath, string sourceContext, Exception exceptionDetail, string hostName, string userId)
{
    try
    {

       var request = new RestRequest(new Uri(_ddUrl + "?ddtags=Env:" + _environment + ", 
        UserID:" + userId), Method.Post);
       request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
       request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");

       string serializedMessage = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(messages);
       request.AddParameter("application/json", serializedMessage, 
       ParameterType.RequestBody);

     _restClient.ExecutePost(request);

  }
  catch(exception ex)
  {
  }
}


and I am calling DatadogLogger.Log.Information(......) everywhere
My question here is as I am using single object of _restClient instance for pushing log to datadog for all logging in webforms. Will I get race condition and get into deadlock situation
The reason why I created single instance of _restClient is if I create instance every time there can be socketexception or the http pool may be out of connections.
